# Is there a way to have multiple external IP addresses with Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with a VPC and I want to have multiple environments (workers) with different IP addresses.  I don't need them to be static, I would actually prefer them to change regularly if possible.  The reason they are in a VPC is to do peering with MongoDB Atlas.

Is there a way to have multiple environments in a VPC with dynamic external IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

It is, but only by setting up different environments in an application. You can have as many as you can afford.

Then you will have an elb per beanstalk env. If you don't want to use the elb, it should be possible to simply use the beanstalk endpoint for ingress.

EDIT:

Beanstalk setup is split into applications and environments. You can deploy the same application to multiple environments. That way you can have multiple endpoints with a single beanstalk app. Here's some more info about it:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.deploy-existing-version.html

Comment: Thanks. That's great to hear but can you give me more details/instructions?  I'm pretty new to AWS.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I really appreciate your help.  I'm new to AWS and am still trying to wrap my head around this.  I have an Elastic Beanstalk application with multiple environments in a VPC.  It's still not clear to me what all these components do.  It sounds like I need to add multiple env (not scale one env?) and then add an elastic load balancer to each env?  How do I force the ip address to change?